# how do I create a popup menu like when you push the bookmark icon in safari.. SEE PIC

Tags: iphone

Hope this isn't a lame question but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to make a pop-up button menu like the image I've attached from my phone. Any help is appreciated!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMbRg.png]

Answer (score 2):

That control is a UIActionSheet.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html